# find point of x contiguous responses

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the point at which participants reach 8 contiguous responses in a row. The data is from a category learning task so the variable would look like:

```
R> data
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1..
```

I'm trying to find the trial number at which participants achieved our criterion for learning - 8 correct responses in a row (1 represent a correct response). So i would want to return 18 from the above example, since it's on the 18th trial that the participant reached 8 correct responses in row.

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere. I looked around fair bit and found a few similar problems but nothing that I could figure out how to directly apply to my problem. I just started using R today (switching from SPSS) so I'm still learning.

Thanks in advance! Let me know if i need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rle` offers a way to look at lengths of runs. First find all runs equal to or greater than 8 with value == 1. Then sum up all the lengths prior to that and add 8.

```
> which( rle(x)$values==1 & rle(x)$lengths >= 8)
[1] 5
```

If there are more than one then take the minimum and subtract one from that for an index:

```
> sum(rle(x)$lengths[ 1:(min(which(rle(x)$lengths >= 8))-1) ]) + 8
[1] 18
```

Comment: nice answer (+1)! Thanks for showing `rle`, another useful function.

Comment: Thanks @DWin. Would this give me the minimum run of 8 or the first time a run of 8 occurred. What I'm looking for is the first time a run of 8 occurred. If I'm understanding you code correctly (which I'm probably not) i think it would give me the minimum run of 8. Is that right?

Comment: Its the minimum index value that satisfies your specification. It's not the minimum length run that is >= 8. Whe I run it on x <- c(x, 0, rep(1,8) ), it still gives 18.

Answer (score 3):

Setting

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

here are two ways:

1) **embed**. Using `embed` find the first row of 1's as follows:

```
> which(rowSums(embed(x, 8)) == 8)[1] + 8 - 1
[1] 18
```

2) **rollapply**. Its a bit less tricky with the zoo package.  With that we take the rolling sum of the last 8 values and then find the time where it first becomes 8:

```
> library(zoo)
> r <- rollapply(zoo(x), 8, sum, align = "right")
> time(r[r == 8][1])
[1] 18
```

Comment: wow! thank you for the quick response. this community is fantastic. much appreciated!

Comment: that is awesome (+1)! I have taken a note of `embed`, thanks for pointing my attention there.

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution with a loop:

```
check_continous_values <- function(d, n) {
    for (i in n:length(d)) {
        if (sum(d[(i-(n-1)):i]) == n) return(i)
    }   
}
```

See it in action:

```
> d <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
> check_continous_values(d,8)
[1] 18
```